# Jupyter notebook stdout capture on windows

Tags: windows, scikit-learn, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have Jupyter Notebook installed via Anaconda running on anaconda python 3.5, windows 10 x64 (package versions: http://pastie.org/10748484)

Notebook doesn't capture and display stdout produced during cell execution (for example verbose output of sklearn methods), instead it is displayed in console used to start Jupyter notebook.

While on other platforms (osx 10.11 and ubuntu 15.10) messages are displayed correctly in cell output during cell execution.

Comment: If you `print()` something, do you still see it in the notebook? scikit-learn might be producing output at a lower level and it's not being redirected.

Comment: it prints, but only when block finishes execution (unlike other platforms)

Comment: That's bizarre. Do you see that behaviour even on a completely new notebook, or is it starting when you import something (maybe sklearn)? I wonder if something is trying to do extra input capturing and accidentally making it worse on Windows.

Comment: Same even for empty notebook (just imported sleep from time)